# Specifying some points in rectangular coordinates and other points in polar coordinates

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to draw a right triangle inscribed in a circle on the Cartesian plane. In the following code, a circle of radius 3 and center (1,1) is drawn. One side of the triangle, the hypotenuse, is drawn - it is the diameter through (1,1) that is vertical.  The endpoints of this diameter are two vertices of the triangle; they are labeled A and C.  I would like to specify B using polar coordinates - with an angle measure of -135 degrees or -150 degrees.  (I did not specify the coordinates of B in rectangular coordinates.  So, no triangle is drawn by the following code.)

There is one other modification to the display that I would like.  Vertical line `\ell` should be drawn in light blue, light green, or light gray.  I remember seeing an option for `help lines` in the manual.  Would this draw `\ell` the way I want it drawn?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{mathtools,systeme,array}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=3in,axis equal image,clip=false,
axis lines=middle,
xmin=-3,xmax=5,
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
ymin=-5,ymax=5,
restrict y to domain=-5:5,
enlargelimits={abs=0.25cm},
axis line style={latex-latex},
ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]

\draw (1,1) circle (3);
\draw [fill] (1,1) circle [radius=1.5pt] node[anchor=west,font=\tiny]{$(1, \, 1)$};
\addplot [dashed,latex-latex,line width=0.5\pgflinewidth,domain=-5:5] (1,x) node [pos=0.1, anchor=north west, font=\footnotesize] {$\ell$};


\draw (axis cs:1,4) coordinate(A) node[above right]{$A$};
%\draw (axis cs:) coordinate(B) node[above left]{$B$};
\draw (axis cs:1,-2) coordinate(C) node[below right]{$C$};

\end{axis}

%\draw[blue] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
%\tkzMarkRightAngle(A,B,C);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You mean you want to specify the rotation of B around the center of the circle don't you? (so that there is a right angle at <ABC)

Comment: Yes. B is a point on the circle. With respect to coordinate axes intersecting at (1,1), B should be rotated 110 degrees.

Comment: Your graph is nice, but I want the code that I posted to be used with the modifications needed to plot B.

Answer (score 6):

with `tikz`

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
%\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\def\ang{60}
\def\radius{3cm}
\def\mypoint{3}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[latex-latex,thick,gray!50] (-5,0) -- (5,0)node[right]{$x$};
    \draw[latex-latex,thick, gray!50] (0,-5) -- (0,5)node[above]{$y$};
    \begin{scope}[shift={(1,1)}]
     \draw (0,0)node[circle,inner sep=2pt, fill](o){} circle (\radius);
     \draw [dashed,latex-latex,blue] (0,5) -- node [pos=0.9, anchor=north west, font=\footnotesize] {$\ell$}
                              (0,-5);
     \coordinate [label=above right:A] (A) at (\ang:\radius);
     \coordinate [label=below left:C] (C) at (180+\ang:\radius);
     \coordinate [label=above left:B] (B)  at (\mypoint*\ang:\radius);
     \draw[blue] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And more versatile `tkz-euclide`

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,svgnames,usenames,dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(3,-4){A}\tkzDefPoint(8,4){B}\tkzDefPoint(1,5){C}
\tkzDefMidPoint(A,B) \tkzGetPoint{O}
\tkzInterLC(C,A)(O,A) \tkzGetSecondPoint{M}
\tkzInterLC(C,B)(O,A) \tkzGetFirstPoint{N}
\tkzInterLL(B,M)(A,N) \tkzGetPoint{I}
\tkzDrawCircle[diameter](A,B)
\tkzDrawSegments(A,M B,N A,B B,M A,N)
\tkzMarkRightAngles[fill=Maroon!20](A,M,B A,N,B)
\tkzLabelPoints[below](O,A,B)
\tkzLabelPoint[above left](M){$M$}
\tkzLabelPoint[above](N){$N$}
\tkzDrawPoints[color=Maroon](O,A,B)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is the version retaining `axis` environment:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis equal,
axis lines=middle,
xmin=-3,xmax=5,
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
ymin=-5,ymax=5,
enlargelimits={abs=0.25cm},
axis line style={draw=gray!30,latex-latex},
xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
\addplot [dashed,latex-latex,line width=0.5\pgflinewidth,domain=-5:5] (1,x) node [pos=0.1, anchor=north west, font=\footnotesize] {$\ell$};

%\draw (1,3) coordinate(A) node[above right]{$A$};
%\draw (axis cs:) coordinate(B) node[above left]{$B$};
%\draw (1,-2) coordinate(C) node[below right]{$C$};

\begin{scope}[yshift=5mm,font=\footnotesize]
\draw (1,0) circle (1.5cm);
\path (1,0) -- +(80:1.5cm) coordinate(A) node[above]{$A$};
\path (1,0) -- +(260:1.5cm) coordinate(C) node[below]{$C$};
\draw [fill] (1,0) circle [radius=1.5pt] node[anchor=west,font=\tiny]{$(1, \, 1)$};
\path (1,0) -- +(135:1.5cm) coordinate(B) node[inner sep=2pt,above left]{$B$};
\draw[blue] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;
\end{scope}
\end{axis}
\tkzMarkRightAngle(A,B,C);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like your graphs.  I want the code to include the code that I posted in order to maintain consistency with the codes for other graphs that I have in a file.  In particular, I want to keep the `axis` environment and use `TikZ`.  (I do like that your lines for the axes are light grey.)

Comment: @Adelyn Sure, but time to go to bed now for me. Tomorrow I will update.

Comment: Can you find time today to send me the code?  I want the code to include the code that I posted in order to maintain consistency with the codes for other graphs that I have in a file. In particular, I want to keep the `axis` environment and to use `TikZ`. (I do like that your lines for the axes are light grey, though.)

Comment: @Adelyn I have updated the answer.

Comment: The display is exactly what I want!  (The display of the axes is nice.)  The code is almost what I want.  The only modification I would like is to put the radius measurement in terms of the coordinate system, using the `axis` environment, instead of in terms of the metric system.

Comment: @Adelyn From `pgfplots` version 1.11 onwards `(1,1)` is same as `(axis cs:1,1)`. Hence there is no difference.

Comment: Thanks.  I was, in particular, talking about the way you specified the points A, B, and C on the circle.

Comment: @Adelyn That was the hack! Just to avoid some problems, I used `yshift`.

Comment: For example, in other code in my file, I specified a point - in rectangular coordinates - using the command"\draw (axis cs:-2,1) coordinate(A) node[left]{$A$}" within the axis environment.

Comment: I wasn't sure about the `yshift` command.  Does my analogy with the rectangular coordinate system help?

Answer (score 4):

While you are waiting for an answer about how to define a point on your circle in `pgf` here is a version in [Metapost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107489/what-is-metapost-metafont-and-how-can-i-get-started-using-it) showing you one way to define points on the circumference of a circle.

[image]

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";
newinternal degrees;
degrees := 1/45;

beginfig(1);

u = 1cm;

% axes
path xx, yy; 
xx = (left -- right) scaled 5u;
yy = (down -- up)    scaled 5u;
drawarrow xx withcolor .7 white;
drawarrow yy withcolor .7 white;
label.rt (btex $x$ etex, point 1 of xx);
label.top(btex $y$ etex, point 1 of yy);

% circle and points and line
path C; 
C = fullcircle scaled 6u shifted (1u,1u);

pair a, b, c;
a = point   80 degrees of C;
c = point -100 degrees of C;
b = point  140 degrees of C;

path ell;
ell = yy shifted (xpart center C,0);

% draw the dashed line
draw ell dashed evenly withcolor 0.8[blue,white];

% mark the right angle
draw unitsquare scaled 5 rotated angle (c-b) shifted b withcolor .7 white;

% draw the triangle
draw a -- b -- c -- cycle withcolor .67 blue;

% draw the circle (and center dot) on top
draw C; fill fullcircle scaled 3 shifted center C;

% finally label the points
label(btex $A$ etex, 1.1[center C, a]);
label(btex $C$ etex, 1.1[center C, c]);
label(btex $B$ etex, 1.1[center C, b]);
label.rt(btex $\ell$ etex, point 0.1 of ell);

endfig;
end.
```

Comment: @PaulGessler  Paul, can you give me the code for plotting the vertics of a triangle inscribed on a circle, not centered at the origin?  I want to use the `axis` environment that I provided, which is similar to the way you used the `axis` environment from our previous discussion.  Here, I need to specify points in polar coordinates ... but there is a shift of the center of the circle.

Comment: @PaulGessler  The code provided by Harish may be of help.  The only modification that I would like is to put the radius measurement in terms of the coordinate system, using the `axis` environment, instead of in terms of the metric system.

Answer (score 4):

You can use normal TikZ coordinate specifications including polar coordinates inside an `axis` environment by setting `disabledatascaling`. Note that this will only work if the range of your data isn't too large.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=3in,axis equal image,clip=false,
axis lines=middle,
xmin=-3,xmax=5,
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
ymin=-5,ymax=5,
restrict y to domain=-5:5,
enlargelimits={abs=0.25cm},
axis line style={latex-latex},
ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west},
disabledatascaling
]

\draw (1,1) circle (3);
\draw [fill] (1,1) circle [radius=1.5pt] node[anchor=west,font=\tiny]{$(1, \, 1)$};
\addplot [densely dashed,latex-latex, blue!50,domain=-5:5] (1,x) node [pos=0.1, anchor=north west, font=\footnotesize] {$\ell$};


\draw (axis cs:1,4) coordinate(A) node[above right]{$A$};
\draw (axis cs:1,1) ++(-135:3) coordinate(B) node[below left]{$B$};
\draw (axis cs:1,-2) coordinate(C) node[below right]{$C$};

\draw [ultra thick, red, opacity=0.55, line join=round] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```